# No output from hello world - Qt SDK 2010 - Mingw (gcc 4.6.3) - WindowsXP

Tags: windows, qt, mingw

Qt: `qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.01`
Mingw: `1686-mingw32-gcc-4.6.3-release` :

The **.pro** file:

```
TEMPLATE    = app
TARGET      = 
SOURCES     += ef.cpp
DEPENDPATH  += .
INCLUDEPATH += .
```

The **.cpp**:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printf ("\nhjhjk\n");
}
```

The compilation and the executable output is as follows:

[image]

The executable called `temp` and an object file called `ef.o` get created in the `debug` folder.

I have edited the `qmake.conf` file as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13227354/warning-cannot-find-entry-symbol-nable-stdcall-fixup-defaulting)

**The print statement doesn't get printed. Please help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding 
CONFIG+=console
to your .pro file

Comment: "Extremely" grateful to you. I had spent looking in wrong direction past 2 days.

Comment: I think this is a windows issue. Linux doesn't "need" that statement.

Comment: Yes, from the reference documentation it is written : "The target is a Win32 console application (app only). The proper include paths, compiler flags and libraries will automatically be added to the project.", So yes it is only true on Windows.